# Error on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, eventvalidation

I have a webpage that has a grid on it. When you click edit, a popup modal window opens. Inside the popup modal window, there is a grid and below it a dropdownlist and save button. When you click save, the selected value is inserted in the grid located in the modal window.

Everything works fine for the first time,  however if you already close the modal window and you happen to do the process all over again (Click edit on the first grid > modal window shows > selects an item on the ddl > hit save button) a postback error happens. Im using an update panel and I also added a postbacktrigger to the add button inside the modal window..

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

Code in the edit button of the first grid (this calls the modal window to open)

```
 protected void grd_depreciation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Guid DepID = new Guid(grd_depreciation.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values[0].ToString());

        //Show the Depreciation Modal Popup
        EditModalDepPopup.Show();
        //btnModalDepreciation_Click(sender,e);

        //checks the type of depreciation.. Network or Equipment
        DropDownList ddldescriptiondep = (DropDownList)(grd_depreciation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlDescriptionDep"));
        var incotype = (ddldescriptiondep.SelectedItem).ToString();
        populategrd_Editdepreciation(DepID, incotype);

    }
```

Here's the code in the add button inside the modal window (the one that causes the error):

```
 MarginAnalysi checkmarginanalysisid = MarginAnalysisAssumption_worker.get(a => a.ProjectCode == lbl_projectCode.Text).SingleOrDefault();
            DepreciationMatrix tblDepreciationMatrix = new DepreciationMatrix();

            tblDepreciationMatrix.DepMatrixID = Guid.NewGuid();
            tblDepreciationMatrix.DepID = new Guid(ViewState["DepID"].ToString());
            tblDepreciationMatrix.IncCapexOpexID = new Guid(ddDepreciationModalEmpty.SelectedValue);
            DepreciationMatrix_worker.insert(tblDepreciationMatrix);
            DepreciationMatrix_worker.submit();

 EditModalDepPopup.Show();

            populategrd_Editdepreciation(new Guid(ViewState["DepID"].ToString()), ViewState["incotype"].ToString());
```

Code for to populate the grid on modal window:

```
//Populate Edit Depreciaiton Grid on Modal
    public void populategrd_Editdepreciation(Guid DepID, string incotype)
    {
        ViewState["DepID"] = DepID;
        ViewState["incotype"] = incotype;
        var x = from a in DepreciationMatrix_worker.get(a => a.DepID == DepID)
                select new { a.DepMatrixID, a.IncCapexOpexID };

        grd_Editdepreciation.DataSource = x;
        grd_Editdepreciation.DataBind();

        //Populate dropdownlist on edit depreciation modal

        MarginAnalysi checkmarginanalysisid = MarginAnalysisAssumption_worker.get(a => a.ProjectCode == lbl_projectCode.Text).SingleOrDefault();

        //Selects eithers Equipment or Network Depreciation
        string test = incotype.ToUpper();

        if (test.Contains("EQUIPMENT"))
        {
            var dropdowndepreciationmodal = from a in tblIncCapexOpex_worker.get(a => a.MarginAnalysisID == checkmarginanalysisid.MarginAnalysisID && a.IncCoTypeID == "CAPEX" && a.DepreciationTypeID == "EQUIPMENT")
                                            select new { text = a.Description, value = a.IncCapexOpexID };

            populateDropdownlist(ddDepreciationModalEmpty, dropdowndepreciationmodal, true);
        }
        else
        {
            var dropdowndepreciationmodal = from a in tblIncCapexOpex_worker.get(a => a.MarginAnalysisID == checkmarginanalysisid.MarginAnalysisID && a.IncCoTypeID == "CAPEX" && a.DepreciationTypeID == "NETWORK")
                                            select new { text = a.Description, value = a.IncCapexOpexID };

            populateDropdownlist(ddDepreciationModalEmpty, dropdowndepreciationmodal, true);
        }



    }
```

Aspx Code for the Modal Pop out. This code is located inside an updatepanel tag.

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnModalDepreciation" CssClass="popup_ButtonsHide" runat="server"
                                                                Text="Click here to show the modal" /><cc1:ModalPopupExtender BehaviorID="test4"
                                                                    ID="EditModalDepPopup" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnModalDepreciation"
                                                                    PopupControlID="DivEditDepTab" Drag="True" PopupDragHandleControlID="DepPopupHeader"
                                                                    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True">
                                                                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                                                            <div id="DivEditDepTab" style="display: none;" class="popupConfirmation2">
                                                                <div class="popup_Container">
                                                                    <div class="popup_Titlebar" id="DepPopupHeader">
                                                                        <div class="TitlebarLeft">
                                                                            Depreciation Items</div>
                                                                        <div class="TitlebarRight">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="popup_Body">
                                                                        Depreciation Details
                                                                        <br />
                                                                        <asp:Table ID="Table25" runat="server" Width="400px">
                                                                            <asp:TableRow>
                                                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                    <asp:GridView ID="grd_Editdepreciation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                                                        Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="grd_Editdepreciation_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="grd_Editdepreciation_RowDeleting"
                                                                                        OnRowEditing="grd_Editdepreciation_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grd_Editdepreciation_RowUpdating"
                                                                                        OnRowDataBound="grd_Editdepreciation_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="DepMatrixID">
                                                                                        <Columns>
                                                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Depreciation" SortExpression="Depreciation">
                                                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDepreciationModal" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenIncCapexOpexID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("IncCapexOpexID") %>' />
                                                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDepreciationModal" runat="server" Enabled="False" Width="100%">
                                                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenIncCapexOpexID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("IncCapexOpexID") %>' />
                                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateDepModal" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                                                                                        Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"
                                                                                                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton></EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditDepModal" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                                                                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteDepModal" runat="server"
                                                                                                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                                                   <%-- <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="confirm1" TargetControlID ="btnDeleteDepModal" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this?" runat="server">
                                                                                                    </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>--%>
                                                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                        </Columns>
                                                                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                                            No Data Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                                                </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                                                                        </asp:Table>
                                                                        <asp:Table ID="Table26" runat="server" Width="400px">
                                                                            <asp:TableRow>
                                                                                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Depreciation</asp:TableHeaderCell></asp:TableRow>
                                                                            <asp:TableRow>
                                                                                <asp:TableCell Width="70%">
                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDepreciationModalEmpty" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell Width="30%">
                                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDepreciationItem" runat="server" Text="Add" Height="26px" OnClick="btnAddDepreciationItem_Click"
                                                                                        Width="70%" /></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
                                                                        </asp:Table>
                                                                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary22" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddDepreciationModal" />
                                                                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary23" runat="server" ValidationGroup="DeleteDepreciationModal" />
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="popup_Buttons">
                                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelDepreciationModal" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="CancelDepreciationItem_Click" /></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: you said  `i also added a postbacktrigger to the add button inside the modal window`? did you try it without the `postbacktrigger`? Check [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx](ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation Method (String))

Comment: @OkayGuy yes I already did.Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this question to get an idea as to what is wrong.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572928/168371

The problem is not in your code but some control which is not inside an update panel and has old values in markup.

Please comment for any further assistance.

Comment: hi, ive pasted the aspx code already. please be aware that i only pasted the code where the modalpopout was created. I cannot paste the others since the aspx was too big.